# Google Cloud Run Deployment for HTTP Request Giving 503 Service Unavailable Using Python Flask APIs

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-run, google-api-python-client, http-status-code-503, google-cloud-shell

I have the following simple python code in a main.py:

```
from flask import Flask

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        # Create the Flask app
        self.app = Flask(__name__)

        # Set up routes
        self.setup_routes()

    def setup_routes(self):
        @self.app.route('/healthcheck', methods=['GET'])
        def HealthCheck():
            return "Successful.", 200


if __name__ == '__main__':
    api_app = TestClass()
    api_app.run()
```

I also have `requirements.txt` file defined in the same directory:

```
Flask==2.2.5
```

I try to deploy my main.py script to the Cloud Run though the cloud shell terminal by running the following command:

```
gcloud run deploy test-api \
    --region europe-west2 \
    --platform managed \
    --allow-unauthenticated \
    --port 8080 \
    --source .
```

The deployment finishes successfully but when I run a GET request for /healthcheck endpoint, I get the following error saying 503 Service Unavailable. The following logs are from Postman:

```
GET https://test-api-<hash>-uc.a.run.app/healthcheck
503
1470 ms
Network
addresses: {…}
local: {…}
address: "10.33.72.107"
family: "IPv4"
port: 62624
remote: {…}
address: "216.239.36.53"
family: "IPv4"
port: 443
tls: {…}
reused: false
authorized: true
authorizationError: null
cipher: {…}
name: "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
standardName: "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
version: "TLSv1/SSLv3"
protocol: "TLSv1.3"
ephemeralKeyInfo: {}
peerCertificate: {…}
Request Headers
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.32.3
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: d7815d67-cddc-4e1a-a284-3f2f87e68427
Host: idam-crun-3ml3jglobq-uc.a.run.app
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Response Headers
content-type: text/plain
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: f5fb87e0fe9045d5f4ffbd758148c521;o=1
Date: Fri, 11 Aug 2023 10:48:39 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 19
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
Response Body
Service Unavailable
```

The Cloud Run logs:

```
2023-08-11 11:48:38.075 BST
GET503954 B1.1 sPostmanRuntime/7.32.3 https://test-api-<hash>-uc.a.run.app/healthcheck
Open in Logs Explorer
{
httpRequest: {
latency: "1.068845188s"
protocol: "HTTP/1.1"
remoteIp: "194.75.103.85"
requestMethod: "GET"
requestSize: "430"
requestUrl: "https://test-api-<hash>-uc.a.run.app/healthcheck"
responseSize: "954"
serverIp: "216.239.36.53"
status: 503
userAgent: "PostmanRuntime/7.32.3"
}
insertId: "64d612070004ee71aefc0b3e"
labels: {
instanceId: "00e676007311ee49f7e01184f14ef22c90751f2ed4458be7909fe0cd4c40582d14379a603ccf94a6f27aed7f831c63b188d1791ed695956d21c35cf4d0db718a80b0"
}
logName: "projects/<project-id>/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Frequests"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-08-11T10:48:39.331516408Z"
resource: {
labels: {5}
type: "cloud_run_revision"
}
severity: "ERROR"
spanId: "17589476964113833446"
textPayload: "The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or connection to the instance had an error. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#malformed-response-or-connection-error"
timestamp: "2023-08-11T10:48:38.075372Z"
trace: "projects/<project-id>/traces/f5fb87e0fe9045d5f4ffbd758148c521"
traceSampled: true
}
```

The GET request was running well with the intended output saying 'Successful' yesterday but now, I keep getting 503 error.

I am currently running on the free trial and have tested the deployment on another Region (us-central1) as well but no change. I set the port to 8080 but in the logs it shows me 443.

I have just started learning about GCP so I appreciate if anyone can share their knowledge to guide me fix the issue or point me out to the right direction to help me out.
If more information is needed please let me know and I will be happy to share.

Thanks in advance!

The expectation was when I run the GET request command in the Postman, I expect to get a string output with 200 success.